# Equivalente DISTF do Excel no R

Tags: r, funções, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber se existe no software R uma função semelhante a função do software Excel, DISTF?

A função DISTF do excel retorna a distribuição de probabilidade F (de cauda direita) (nível de diversidade) para dois conjuntos de dados. Você pode usar esta função para determinar se dois conjuntos de dados têm graus de diversidade diferentes.

DISTF é calculada como `DISTF =P( F>x )`, onde `F` é uma variável aleatória que possui uma distribuição `F` com `graus_liberdade1` e `graus_liberdade2` de liberdade.

Exemplo: `DISTF = 8,49;1;40 = 0,00582`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

se quiser a função de distribuição, você pode fazer:

```
pf(8.49,1,40, lower.tail=FALSE)
0.00582054498262771
```